# How to mark notification as read for particular user and post in laravel 5?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, notifications

I want to mark a notification as read for a user who views a particular post

```
public function show(Post $post)
    {

        $notification_for_user = auth()->user()->unreadNotifications()->where("data['post_id']", $post->id)->first()->update(['read_at' => now()]);

        return view('post.show', compact('post'));
    }
```

It gives this error

```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'data['post_id']' in 'where clause'
```

So how can i access data column's post_id to delete that particular notification for the user when it is displayed.

This is how it is stored in data column

```
{"post_id":8,"title":"Example Post...}
```

Comment: ` $notification_for_user = auth()->user()->unreadNotifications()->whereRaw("data.post_id", $post->id)->first()->update(['read_at' => now()]);`

Comment: still gives same error: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'data.post_i‌​d' in 'where clause'

Comment: show us your `unreadNotifications()` function and it would be better if you can update your question with db schema.

Comment: I have used laravel's notifications from here https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/notifications#database-notifications

Comment: May be these posts can help you. Have a look: 1. [New JSON-column where() and update() syntax in Laravel 5.3](https://mattstauffer.com/blog/new-json-column-where-and-update-syntax-in-laravel-5-3/) 2. [Laravel JSON documents faster lookup using generated columns](https://themsaid.com/laravel-mysql-json-colum-fast-lookup-20160709/)

Comment: then use `markAsRead` as doc said

Comment: Seems the columns is json. Take a look at https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/queries#json-where-clauses

Answer (score 2):

Please check the following code.

```
use Illuminate\Notifications\DatabaseNotification;

    $notification = DatabaseNotification::find( $request->notification_id );
                $notification->update(['read_at' => now()]);
                $notification->save();
```

Answer (score 0):

In web.php:

`Route::get('/read/notifications', 'Admin\NotificationController@readNotification');`

In Controller:

```
public function readNotification() {
$user = Auth::user();
$user->unreadNotifications()->update(['read_at' => now()]);
}
```